# Adaboost Implementation (obtaining weak classifier functional form in R)

Tags: r, adaboost

I am trying to use Adaboost in CRAN-R for a classification problem.  I cannot find any R packages that actually output the weak classifier functional form (ex. hi(x) * I (Y > z) that i could then program as a scoring algorithm.  Can anyone help point me to a package that could provide these functions / coefficients?  Thanks!

Comment: If you look at the `predict` method for your Adaboost-fitting functions, you'll see how each package author has implemented scoring. This should help you roll it yourself.